# Where is a good place for a commonly used method... in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, helper

I have a method that I've started to use in multiple models for Webscraping, where is the best place to keep it?  Should I put it in the application_controller, application _helper?  I'm not sure where a good place is to put it for multiple models to use it?

```
  def self.retryable(options = {}, &block)
    opts = { :tries => 1, :on => Exception }.merge(options)

    retry_exception, retries = opts[:on], opts[:tries]

    begin
      return yield
    rescue retry_exception
      retry if (retries -= 1) > 0
    end

    yield
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put retryable.rb in lib/

```
module Retryable
  extend self

  def retryable(options = {}, &block) # no self required
  ...
  end
end
```

Use it:

```
Retryable.retryable { ... }
```

or including namespace:

```
include Retryable
retryable { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a module. An example from the [Altered Beast](http://github.com/courtenay/altered_beast/tree/master) project: (I often look in other projects how they solve specific problems)

```
# app/models/user/editable.rb
module User::Editable
  def editable_by?(user, is_moderator = nil)
    is_moderator = user.moderator_of?(forum) if is_moderator.nil?
    user && (user.id == user_id || is_moderator)
  end
end
```

And in the models:

```
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include User::Editable
  # ...
end

# app/models/topic.rb
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  include User::Editable
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Any particular reason you put it in models/user rather than lib?

Comment: i'm not sure how that works... they're not referencing editable_by? in the other models themselves. I tried placing mine in a similar folder #app/models/scrapers/retryable.rb, module Scrapers::Retryable and then referencing it as "include Scrapers::Retryable" but it gives me "undefined method `retryable' for Get_Data:Class"